# Cambio codigo status en ResponseEntity spring

Tags: java, spring

Estoy construyendo un microservicio en spring boot que consume un servicio, el punto es que **cuando el servicio no tiene datos me envía un status 400 y un array vacío**, lo que a su vez genera un status 400 en spring. por esto necesito que cuando el servicio me envíe un status 400 yo pueda ignorarlo y solo devolver el array vacío.

> return ResponseEntity.status(OK).body(getData());

Answer (score 2):

Cuando consumes un servicio tienes que revisarlo, y en caso de tener el 400 del que hablas, no retornes directo el `ResponseEntity.status(OK).body(getData());`
haz el `JSONObject data = body.getData()` (o lo que estés retornando)
y revisa la variable data, luego de eso construye tu respuesta, o en la implementación donde estas consumiendo el servicio.

Answer (score 1):

Eso debes controlarlo en lo servicios del Rest, te pongo un ejemplo

```
 @Override
public Cita crearCita(Cita cita) throws ExcepcionServicio {
    Date fechaDHoy = new Date();
    Date fecha = cita.getfHoraCita();
    String nss = cita.getPaciente().getnSS();
    String nLicencia = cita.getMedico().getnLicencia();
    List<Cita> citasPacienteEsaHora = repositorioC.buscarCitaXPacienteYHora(nss, fecha);
    List<Cita> citasMedicoEsaHora = repositorioC.buscarCitaXMedicoYHora(nLicencia, fecha);
    if (citasPacienteEsaHora.size() > 0) {
        throw new ExcepcionServicio("Usted ya tiene una cita en esa fecha y hora");
    }
    if (citasMedicoEsaHora.size() > 0) {
        throw new ExcepcionServicio("El medico no tiene hueco a esa hora ese dia");
    }
    if (fecha.before(fechaDHoy)) {
        throw new ExcepcionServicio("La fecha debe ser posterior a hoy");
    }
    Optional<Medico> m = repositorioM.findById(nLicencia);
    Optional<Paciente> p = repositorioP.findById(nss);
    if (!m.isPresent()) {
        throw new ExcepcionServicio("El numero de licencia no existe");
    }
    if (!p.isPresent()) {
        throw new ExcepcionServicio("El numero de SS no existe");
    }
    cita.setPaciente(p.get());
    cita.setMedico(m.get());
    return this.repositorioC.save(cita);
}
```

como ves segun lo que le envies no sigue adelante no da error,
luego en la aplicacion muestro lo posible errores que de

```
private SwingWorker<Response<List<PacienteDTO>>, Void> cargaPaciente() {
    return new SwingWorker<Response<List<PacienteDTO>>, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Response<List<PacienteDTO>> doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Response<List<PacienteDTO>> listP = listarPaciente();
            return listP;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            Response<List<PacienteDTO>> resultado;
            try {
                resultado = get();
                if (resultado.isSuccessful()) {
                    listaP = resultado.body();
                    CmbPaciente.removeAllItems();
                    CmbPaciente.addItem("");
                    for (int i = 0; i < listaP.size(); i++) {
                        CmbPaciente.addItem(listaP.get(i).getnSS());
                    }
                } else {
                    JsonObject convertedObject = new Gson().fromJson(resultado.errorBody().string(), JsonObject.class);
                    JsonElement msgElement = convertedObject.get("message");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de carga " + msgElement.toString());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fallo de comunicacion " + ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AniadirCitas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Si el resultado no es correcto osea no es un codigo 200 no sigue con lo que tenga que hacer